# Evince does not go to the next occurance of a searched string

Tags: 14.04, evince

In Evince, I follow the following steps to search a string in the document:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>
2. Type the string
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to go to the next occurrence.

Evince gets stuck at the same page as I keep on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This is a known bug, waiting a backport to 14.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1263088

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the bug, but it seems that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (Go to the previous search result) behaves correctly.

It's not ideal, but at least you can browse your matching patterns.

A bug is already filled in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1263088

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+g also misbehaves.